# How to search for posts/videos commented on by someone via graph search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-search, facebook-graph-search

It seems like the comments search is limited to "**photos**" for now since queries such as "**posts** commented on by {name}" or "**videos** commented on by {name}" simply don't work. Is there an alternative way to retrieve results for above scenarios?

Note: "**photos** commented on by {name}" does work. Am I missing something or did Facebook drop support for public posts/videos?

Comment: Use https://stalkface.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Facebook Graph Search was retired.